# Check if day exists between timestamps

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I am trying to figure out if a date exists between two unix timestamps regardless of year.  For example, lets say I have the date December 12th, but does not contain the year.  How would I check if December 12th exists between the timestamps of 1353369600 and 1358640000 (first timestamp equals Nov. 20th, 2012; second equals Jan. 20, 2013).  I am programming the application in PHP, however if you know how to do this in a different language, please post your thoughts so I can try to work through the logic.

Thanks in advance

Update: here is the answer!
Use strtotime and set the second parameter to the beginning timestamp :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `strtotime` to turn the string to timestamp and then compare. If the string don't contain year, then  the year default is current year.

```
$ts = strtotime("December 12th");
if ($ts >= 1353369600 && $ts <= 1358640000 ) {//....}
```

Comment: The year needs to be whatever year is between timestamp A and timestamp B, and since the timestamps can fall between a year change, I am not quite sure how to get a timestamp that would fall between those dates.

Comment: Right, as xdazz said. You convert the date you're testing into a unix timestamp. So whether you're hardcoding the date into `strtotime`, or if you're collecting form data, it doesn't really matter. You pass as much information about the date that you have.

Comment: If the current year is 2012 like in my example, your code will work.  However, if use the years 2013 and 2014, the timestamp will be using the incorrect year (2012 instead of 2013/2014).

Answer (score 0):

You can check every year between the timestamps and see if there is the desired day in between them.

```
function inBetween($day, $month, $from, $to)
{
    $from_year = date('Y', $from);
    $to_year = date('Y', $to);

    if($from_year == $to_year)
    {
        $time = mktime(12,0,0,$month,$day, $from_year);

        return $time > $from && $time < $to;
    }
    elseif($from_year < $to_year)
    {
        for($i=$from_year;$i<=$to_year;$i++)
        {
            $time = mktime(12,0,0,$month,$day, $i);
            if($time > $from && $time < $to) return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}

var_dump(inBetween(12, 12, 1353369600, 1358640000));
```